# Prove that $x\leq \sin^{-1}x\leq \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ on $(0,1)$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Prove that $x\leq \sin^{-1}x\leq \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ on $(0,1)$.

Below is my attempt.

The inequality can be simplified to $1\leq \dfrac{\sin^{-1}x}{x}\leq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.
Let $f(x)=\sin^{-1}x.$

By the Mean Value Theorem, since $f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$, there exists some $c\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=\dfrac{f(1)-f(0)}{1}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\Rightarrow\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Since $0<c<1$, we have that $1<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}$ and since $x\in (0,1), 0<\sin^{-1}x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. As well, it can be shown that $\sin x < x\Rightarrow x < \sin^{-1}x, x\in(0,1)$. But how do I show that $\dfrac{\sin^{-1}x}{x}\leq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}, x\in(0,1)?$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that $\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}<\sin^{-1}b-\sin^{-1}a<\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}$ by using Mean Value Theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427411/how-to-prove-that-fracb-a-sqrt1-a2-sin-1b-sin-1a-fracb-a-sq)

Comment: Set $a=0$ and $b=x$.

Comment: @MartinR I asked a stupid question.