# Inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having trouble proving this:

$$ sin^{－1}(x)<\frac {x}{\sqrt {1－x^2}}\;\;\;\forall\;x\in\;]0;1[ $$

Is there a way to prove that ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2427411/42969

Comment: One way might be to form g(x) = right minus left, and then use calc to try to show the result is always greater than zero, by looking at the derivative of g(x) and so on.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint: Consider how we generally go about finding maximums and minimums of functions. From there, the analysis should be relatively simple.

Comment: It is simpler than that : just make the change of variable : $x = \sin \alpha$ then use a classical inequality.